# Java: Local variable scope

Tags: java, arrays, return, try-catch

I get an error saying that the compiler cannot find my variable "complexArray" but I don't know why. How do I fix my program so that it returns the array of Complex numbers read from the file?

```
public static Complex[] parseFromFile(String fileName) {
    int numOfComplex = 0;
    try {   
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        String firstLine = sc.nextLine();
        firstLine = firstLine.trim();
        numOfComplex = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);
        Complex[] complexArray = new Complex[numOfComplex];
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfComplex; i++) {
            String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
            nextLine = nextLine.trim();
            complexArray[i] = parseComplex(nextLine);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
    return complexArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your complexArray variable is declared inside the try{} scope. Declare it before the try statement.

Complex[] complexArray = null;

Comment: when I declare it as null, it returns as null. for some reason the array is not changing inside the try/catch block

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on from @hemanth

```
public static Complex[] parseFromFile(String fileName) {
        int numOfComplex = 0;
        Complex[] complexArray = new Complex[numOfComplex]; // Need to initialize the array
        try {   
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            String firstLine = sc.nextLine();
            firstLine = firstLine.trim();
            numOfComplex = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);
            complexArray = new Complex[numOfComplex];
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfComplex; i++) {
                String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
                nextLine = nextLine.trim();
                complexArray[i] = parseComplex(nextLine);
                }
            return complexArray;
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception was thrown"); // try adding this to see if an exception is thrown.
        }
        return complexArray;
    } //<<<=== scope of `complexArray` ends here
```

You need to initialize the complexArray object by creating a new Complex array. That is your issue.

I think this may work. if all is well it should enter the try clause. If not it will return the complexArray of size 0. I assume if this happens there is something wrong with the file which means you will need to do something manually?

Comment: Doesn't work either--the reason is because I have to get the length of the array from the file that I am reading, therefore I can't declare the array with its size before I read from the file. But when I do anything in the try/catch block, it doesn't seem to change or affect the array at all

Comment: because then it tells me that i need a return statement after the try/catch. it seems as if it isn't even getting into the try clause.

Comment: @user3277742: please see revised answer and see if that helps

Comment: doesn't work either....that just returns an array of size 0. it doesn't enter the try clause, so all it does is initialize an array of length 0 then return that array. I'm telling you man, I'm so confused haha

Comment: That just means an exception is always being thrown. I am guessing by the Scanner object......make sure you can read in the file which is what I meant earlier if it returns an array of size 0 there is something wrong with IO

Comment: But aren't I catching all exceptions with my try/catch?

Comment: with a try-catch the code in the try block is the code you want to run. If something goes wrong there it goes into the catch clause. What this means is something in the try block is throwing an exception and then the code goes to the catch clause which does nothing and then finally it returns the array

Comment: @user3277742: Please see revised solution. But I believe the culprit is your IO, there is something happening there.

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()). One or more of the scanner methods may be throwing an exception. If you want help on that I think you need to post another question

Answer (score -1):

Put return complexArray statement within the try {} statement

```
public static Complex[] parseFromFile(String fileName) {
int numOfComplex = 0;
try {   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    String firstLine = sc.nextLine();
    firstLine = firstLine.trim();
    numOfComplex = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);
    Complex[] complexArray = new Complex[numOfComplex];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfComplex; i++) {
        String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
        nextLine = nextLine.trim();
        complexArray[i] = parseComplex(nextLine);
    }
 return complexArray;
}
catch(Exception e) {
}
```

}

Comment: this says that I am missing the return statement after the catch

Comment: ok then try placing the return complexArray to where it is and then put Complex[] complexArray = new Complex[numOfComplex]; below int numOfComplex = 0;

Answer (score -1):

since `complexArray` is declared in `try` block, once execution inside the try block is completed `complexArray` is out of scope.

```
      public static Complex[] parseFromFile(String fileName) {
        int numOfComplex = 0;
        try {   
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            String firstLine = sc.nextLine();
            firstLine = firstLine.trim();
            numOfComplex = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);
            Complex[] complexArray = new Complex[numOfComplex];
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfComplex; i++) {
                String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
                nextLine = nextLine.trim();
                complexArray[i] = parseComplex(nextLine);
            }
        } //<<<=== scope of `complexArray` ends here
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
        return complexArray;
    }
```

try this

```
      public static Complex[] parseFromFile(String fileName) {
        int numOfComplex = 0;
        Complex[] complexArray;
        try {   
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            String firstLine = sc.nextLine();
            firstLine = firstLine.trim();
            numOfComplex = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);
            complexArray = new Complex[numOfComplex];
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfComplex; i++) {
                String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
                nextLine = nextLine.trim();
                complexArray[i] = parseComplex(nextLine);
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
        return complexArray;
    } //<<<=== scope of `complexArray` ends here
```

Comment: it says that the variable may not be initialized---I think that what's happening is it's not putting values into the array, and I don't know why